# Does the sanity boost from friendly pigs stack with multiple pigs?

Tags: dont-starve

I read on the Don't Starve Wiki that you receive a sanity boost from a pig in close proximity up to +25 sanity/minute.  But, it doesn't say if having multiple friendly pigs multiplies the effect.

So far, I've discovered that by befriending 3 or more pigs, it keeps several of them close to my side while chopping the same tree.  This minimizes the distance between me and any of the pigs.

But, am I multiplying the sanity boost beyond +25/min by keeping more than one pig around me or just getting it closer to +25/min?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a number for you, but I've experienced that it does in fact stack.

I had two to three pigs next to me, and I noticed that the up-arrow in the sanity circle was thicker and larger than when I just had one pig.

Adding the Top-hat or Garland to the mix made it even bigger.

I cannot gauge the exact amount per minute, though.  This would actually make a great mod for someone!  The ability to see the current rate of change on any of the stats.

Comment: Great mod idea. I wonder why we're only coming up with those now.

Comment: Every idea has to have a first person to come up with it.  I'm not saying I'm the first, but there is always a first guy.  Then, there has to be a first guy to voice it out loud.  Then, there has to be a first guy to contemplate if if can be implemented, etc. etc. etc.  You get the idea.  There are a lot of great ideas being had by people, like you and myself, who can't do anything about them due to our lack of coding experience.  (Well, it holds true for me anyway . . .)